# Extracting string between brackets

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

How can I extract exact string between brackets?

What I tried is:

```
echo "test [test1] test" | grep -Po "(?=\[).*?(?=\])"
```

But the output is:

```
[test1
```

It should be:

```
test1
```

Better to use `grep`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a lookbehind:

```
echo "test [test1] test" | grep -Po "(?<=\[).*?(?=\])"
```

Comment: Thank you...could you tell me what is the role of `<` ?

Comment: @MortezaLSC `(?<=B)A` means find `A` where `B` precedes.

Comment: You can check here for the available lookarounds in regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Why don't you use ``\K`` ? Like ``grep -Po "\[\K.*?(?=\])"``

Answer (score 4):

`awk` should do too:

```
echo "test [test1] test" | awk -F"[][]" '{print $2}'
test1
```

Or `sed`

```
echo "test [test1] test" | sed 's/[^[]*\[\|\].*//g'
test1
```

Comment: I love `awk` solutions, +1.

Comment: Added a `sed` solution too (not as easy to understand as `awk`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, worth mentioning:

```
echo "test [test1] test" | grep -Po '[^\[]+(?=[\]])'
```

In this case, the pattern `A(?=B)` means: Find `A` where expression `B` follows.

If you want the `[` and `]` you can try this:

```
echo "test [test1] test" | grep -Po '[\[].*[\]]'
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer having negated `]` to prevent greedy matching:

```
echo "test [test1] test [test2] xyz" | grep -Po "(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=\])"
```

Output:

```
test1
test2
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work with any version of sed as it's just a plain old BRE:

```
$ echo "test [test1] test" | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/'
test1
```